# How to use a select form to change language with PHP $_GET and $_POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, get, multilingual

I have to apologize if this answer has already been answered before, I've looked for it and found something partially useful but nothing that answered my needs.

I'm new to PHP and I want to make a simple website with multilingual support. Translations are provided by specific arrays according to the page they are in. I will use a `foreach` loop to get the translation. User is allowed to change the default language with a `select` html tag. I am partially able to achieve this goal in this way:

Firstly, with a simple function I look for the browser language and set it as language fall-back:

```
function browser_lang() {
  $rawLang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

  if($rawLang == 'it') {
    $browserLang = 'it';
  } else {
    $browserLang = 'en';
  }

  return $browserLang;
}
```

In the `index.php` file I set the fall-back language in this way:

```
<?php
    // Include the browser_lang() and other functions

    if(isset($_POST['set_language'])) {
        $lang = strip_bad_chars($_GET['lang']);
    } else {
        $lang = browser_lang();
    }
?>

<html lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
```

Later in the html I added a form with some select tag that allows to select languages:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="set_language" id="custom-lang">
    <option value="it">Italiano</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="input_language" value="Set Language">
</form>
```

When I load the page for the first time, the script is able to retrieve the browser language, but when I select a custom language, it is not able to change it.

How can I add `?lang=en` or `?lang=it` at the end of the url in order to use `$_GET['lang']` and loop through translations with the `$lang` variable set with that select form?

The entire `index.php`, included the external resources, is:

```
<?php
    function browser_lang() {
        $rawLang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

        if($rawLang == 'it') {
            $browserLang = 'it';
        } else {
            $browserLang = 'en';
        }

        return $browserLang;
    }

    function strip_bad_chars( $input ) {
        $output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "",$input);
        return $output;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['set_language'])) {
        $lang = strip_bad_chars($_GET['lang']);
    } else {
        $lang = browser_lang();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="set_language" id="custom-lang">
            <option value="it">Italiano</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="input_language" value="Set Language">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't `if(isset($_POST['set_language'])) {
        $lang = strip_bad_chars($_GET['lang']);` be `if(isset($_POST['set_language'])) {
        $lang = strip_bad_chars($_POST['lang']);`

Comment: @RobGudgeon it does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `lang` parameter in the URL (which I think makes sense) you can just change your form a bit:

```
<form action="" method="get"><!-- use get instead of post-->
    <select name="lang" id="custom-lang"><!-- change name to lang-->
    ... etc.
```

This way, when the form is submitted, you *will* have `?lang=en` or `?lang=it` in the URL, and you can use

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = strip_bad_chars($_GET['lang']);
} else {
    $lang = browser_lang();
}
```

to set your language.

Comment: the link now looks like this: `?lang=en&input_language=Set+Language`

Comment: @dcdeiv You can remove the `name` attribute from your submit button to get rid of the extra stuff. It isn't really necessary if you've made the other changes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several problems:

1. You're mixing the submission methods (Using *both* POST and GET)
2. You check for `$_POST['set_language']` but expect `$_GET['lang']`
3. The `<select>` menu is named differently to the variable you wish to use in the `<html>` tag's `lang` attribute.

What I'd do is settle on a method; POST *or* GET then change all ref's to GET/POST respectively, and then use *either* "set_language" *or* "lang" as your superglobal ($_GET/$_POST) array key.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
    // Include the browser_lang() and other functions

    if(isset($_POST['input_language'])) {
        $lang1 = $_POST['set_language'];
        if ($lang1 == "Italiano") {
          $lang = "it"
        } else {
          echo "en";
        }
    }
?>

<html lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
```